# Checking bool value of a ViewBag in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a controller method that creates a ViewBag like this

```
  foreach (Site s in sites)
            {              
                var OffReportRows = new Queue<List<string>>();
                ViewBag.showColumns = false;
                if (osiTotal[s.ID] > 0) {
                ViewBag.showColumns = true;

                OffReportRows.Enqueue(new List<string>
                {
                    "Parts",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                });
             }
```

And a view page that checks if the ViewBag value is true

```
    @foreach (Site s in sites)
        {
            if( ViewBag.showColumns == true) {
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">@s.Name</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">Average Cost</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">Average Cost With Labour</td>
            </tr>
             }
```

But it still always returns the columns even if the total is 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried placing break points and debugging your application? Verify the value of `ViewBag.showColumns` in the action and view.

Comment: @jegtugado Yes I have. It always returns true with the way it's currently set up

Comment: Based on your design, you are iterating through `sites` and determining `ViewBag.showColumns` on each iteration. Is this what you really want? the final value will be based on the last entry.

Comment: each osiTotal[s.ID] will have a total. So if that total is not greater than 0, I don't want the columns to be displayed for that site. @jegtugado

Comment: so if osiTotal[3] has a value of 100. I want to display the columns for that site . But if osiTotal[4]  has a value of 0. I don't want it to display the columns for that site @jegtugado

Comment: If each site should have its own `showColumns` then I suggest creating a view model. Something like `SiteVM` with the property `ShowColumns`. So instead of simply using `Site` you return a collection of  `SiteVM` to the view. Hope it makes sense since I'm a bit lazy right now. The flaw in your current design is that the final value of `ViewBag.showColumns` is based on the last entry in `sites` and this variable will be used for all sites regardless of the `osiTotal[s.ID]` evaluation. In your view, use `if((bool)ViewBag.showColumns)` since view doesn't know the `ViewBag` data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello as per your problem what I understood and according to your requirements. I suggest you do mention below things

Create a view model as mention below

```
public class siteViewModel
{
   public int SiteId {get;set;}
   public Bool ShowColumn {get;set;}
}
```

Create a list and set mapping to the site id and add the object to the list as below in your controller.

```
List<siteViewModel> siteData = new List<siteViewModel>();
foreach (Site s in sites)
{
    var OffReportRows = new Queue<List<string>>();
    if (osiTotal[s.ID] > 0)
    {
         // your OffReportRows related code here
         siteData.Add(new siteViewModel() {SiteId =s.ID,ShowColumn =true });
    }
    else
    {
         siteData.Add(new siteViewModel() {SiteId =s.ID,ShowColumn =false });
    }
}
viewbag.MapData = siteData;
```

AT View side do the following changes

```
@{
     List<siteViewModel> data = (List<siteViewModel>)viewbag.MapData;
}

@foreach (Site s in sites)
{
    if(data.Any(a=> a.SiteId==s.ID && a.ShowColumn)) 
    {
      <tr>
            <td style="font-weight : bold;">@s.Name</td>
             // add you fields as per requirements
      </tr>
    }
    else
    {
       // do as per requirements
    }
}
```